# Change value in json field with the appropriate values from other json field in a MySQL select

Tags: mysql, json

I have the following simplified schema and data:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7.22)**:

```
CREATE TABLE `config_remap` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200),
  `addons` json,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requested_remap_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requested_addons` json, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `config_remap` (`id`, `name`, `addons`) 
VALUES(1, 'Remap 1', 
'[{"id": 0,"name": "Addon 0"},
  {"id": 1,"name": "Addon 1"},
  {"id": 2,"name": "Addon 2"}
]');

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `product_name`, `requested_remap_id`, `requested_addons`) 
VALUES (1, 'Audi A4', 1, '[\"0\", \"2\"]');
```

And the following query:

```
select products.id, products.product_name, products.requested_addons, config_remap.name as requested_addon
from products
    left join config_remap on config_remap.id = products.requested_remap_id
```

Which produces the following results:

| id | product_name | requested_addons | requested_addon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi A4 | ["0", "2"] | Remap 1 |

---

I want to change the query so it can replace the IDs of the `requested_addons` with their names from the `config_remap`.`addons`. So the expected result should be similar to this:

| id | product_name | requested_addons | requested_addon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi A4 | ["Addon 0", "Addon 2"] | Remap 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3LLBCjjVY2gWMNzuk5zNG9/0)

**I'm using MySQL 5.7.22**

Comment: Does the amount of separate element in `products.requested_addons` is limited? for example, not more than 5 elements.. The same about `config_remap.addons`.

Comment: @Akina , `config_remap`.`addons` can contain multiple elements. And `products`.`requested_addons` can also have multiple elements. But in general, there are no more than 15 addons to choose from.

Comment: Seems like using a relational design on a relational database would be a better solution and then the queries would be a breeze

Comment: @RiggsFolly how is your comment helping me solve the issue? Sorry, but it doesn't add any value.

Comment: However it has an upvote. There are very few sensible reasons for storing data in a relational database as JSON. It is hard to utilise simply in that form. Fine if its just stuff you want to transport around as a lump, but if you want to maipulate it as part of a query, it becomes less and less sensible the more complex the JSON

Comment: Notice how even @Akina, someone who appears to be a bit of an expert has not tried to offer an answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly , so what is this suppose to mean? Lets not use json in mysql because it is later hard to work with? It is how it is...

Comment: I would suggest it should only be used in specific circumstances. And this woudl appear to be one that does not work well

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products.id, 
       products.product_name,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(config_remap.addon_name) requested_addons, 
       config_remap.name requested_addon
FROM (
  SELECT cr.id, cr.name, 
         JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(cr.addons, CONCAT('$[', numbers.pos, '].id'))) addon_id, 
         JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(cr.addons, CONCAT('$[', numbers.pos, '].name'))) addon_name
  FROM config_remap cr
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 pos UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) numbers
  ) config_remap
JOIN (
  SELECT pr.id, pr.product_name,  pr.requested_remap_id, 
         JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(pr.requested_addons, CONCAT('$[', numbers.pos, ']'))) addon_id
  FROM products pr
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 pos UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) numbers
  ) products USING (addon_id)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 4;
```

| id | product_name | requested_addons | requested_addon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi A4 | ["Addon 0", "Addon 2"] | Remap 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tCUBD-qu)

> in general, there are no more than 15 addons to choose from. – Milen Mihalev

Expand `numbers` synthetic tables accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a little bit concerned about the `numbers` synthetic tables. Can you please explain "SELECT 0 pos UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3"?

Also, is it possible to do this with some temporary tables. Is this going to simplify the query?
It worth mention that, this query is a part of a background running task which is generating a sphinx cache. So it is ok if it is time consuming and using temp tables.

Comment: @MilenMihalev *Can you please explain "SELECT 0 pos UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3"?* https://dbfiddle.uk/W2xO9lt7 Also you may use some system table (which stores not less than 15 rows) as numbers source - for example, `mysql.help_category`. *is it possible to do this with some temporary tables* Of course. Create temptables with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE .. SELECT, use explanational queries, then use these tables instead of subqueries. Do not forget to define indexes by `addon_id` in these tables.